# expanding/animating a div from center when width is 100%

Tags: css, keyframe

I have a div with a border and i used keyframes to expand it onload but I want it to expand from the center rather than left to right.

http://andylilien.com/index2015.html

the css:

```
.navback { 
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:-8px;
width:100%;
height:17px;
background-color:#FFF;
border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
z-index:999;
}   
@-webkit-keyframes expandline{
0%{width:0%;}
50%{width:50%;}
100%{width:100%;}
}
.navback{
-webkit-animation:expandline 2s;
}
```

Comment: so something like
    .navback { 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:-8px;
    width:0;
    height:17px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    z-index:999;
    -webkit-animation:expandline 2s;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    } 
    navback.onload {
    width: 100%;
  
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adjust the height and width as you are doing, but `transform` the element by positioning its left and top appropriately.

Also, you don't really need keyframe animations for this if you're using a common easing function or linear animation.

```css
#expander {
  position:absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 17px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: expandline 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandline{
  0%   { width:   0%; }
  50%  { width:  50%; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="expander"></div>
```

What's happening with the CSS:

- Start the element off in it's initial position (fully styled and positioned, but with 0 width)
- Add a transition to the element defining what attributes will transition, and how long the transition will take

  - Now any time one of the specified attributes changes, it apply a transition rather than instantly applying the change
- Define a class that represents the final state of your element (fully styled and positioned, as in the initial state, but with the width you want)

The expanding from center behavior is the result of:

```
/* #expander will now be positioned relative to the nearest ancestor with a position other than `static`, or the `body` element if nothing else qualifies */
position: absolute;

/* The top of #expander will be 50% down the positioning context's height (i.e., the top of #expander is vertically centered in its parent) */
top: 50%;

/* The left of #expander will be 50% of the positioning context's width (i.e., the left of #expander is horizontally centered in its parent) */
left: 50%;

/* Translate #expander 50% of its own width to the left, and 50% of its own height in the up direction */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Since we don't animate the `transform`, it continues to apply as defined in the initial rule: keep `#expander` vertically and horizontally centered in its parent, regardless of how tall or wide it is.

Now you just use whatever trigger is appropriate (you said you were using `onload`) to apply the expanded class and trigger the transition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks palpatim. Can you post a code snippet that starts from the center and expands evenly from left to right.. that might help me to understand better

Comment: See edited answer; I also expanded a bit on what's happening with the transition. I recommend you look at CSS transitions to get more familiar with their use. They're very powerful, but can be tricky to wrap your head around. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: so something like this: }
.navback { 
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 padding-bottom:-8px;
 width:0;
 height:17px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-top: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
 z-index:999;
 -webkit-animation:expandline 2s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

} 
  navback.onload {
  width: 100%;
  
  }

Comment: With syntax cleanup, yes, something like that. You can take out the `animation` reference and replace it with a `transition: all 2s;` as in the example above.

Comment: i cleaned it up but its not firing http://andylilien.com/index2015a.html  the stylesheet is style_lilien_2015a.css

Comment: Please use a StackOverflow snippet or jsfiddle, jsbin or similar, and only post the code relevant to this problem, so I don't have to try to wade through your entire website.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware that css transitions didn't have the same onload behavior as css keyframes. I've edited my snippet above to go back to keyframes as you originally specified.

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/j4369753/2/ it expands from the middle going left - looking to start from the center and expand both left and right

Comment: Not sure what to say. I forked your fiddle to simplify it a bit, and it works as expected on my browser, animating outward from the center: https://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/cgwvfu68/

Comment: thanks but that fiddle is starting in the middle and extending right thats not what I'm looking for i was able to make it work using 0% { left: 50%; width: 0 } 100% { left: 0; width :100% } see it in action here  http://andylilien.com/index2015.html thanks for taking the time!

Comment: upvote for the distinction between when you require `transition` and when you require `keyframe`

Comment: @REELHERO assuming you're talking about `.navback2` on your site, you don't have the `top` and `left` attributes set as discussed above.