# Jquery:How to expand a div from center of the page

Tags: jquery, css

here i got a nice example what i am looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/30927145/6188148

```
#expander {
  position:absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 17px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: expandline 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandline{
  0%   { width:   0%; }
  50%  { width:  50%; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}
```

but the person who develop the div expand animation used huge css but i like to know how could i do the same using jquery code where div will expand from center of the page. please post a jsfiddle link with sample code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  function animate(percent){
    $( "#expander" ).animate({
      width: percent
    }, 1000);
  }
  animate("50%");
  animate("100%");
});
```

```css
#expander {
  position:absolute;
  height:1px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expander"></div>
```

Comment: what this css you wrote `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` ?

Comment: how could i see your full code. what u stored inside percent variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.animate()` to animate `width`. You can use 2 animations if you want it timed similarly, or you could just use 1 animation and go to `width: 100%`

```js
$('div').animate({
  width: '50%'
},500).animate({
  width: '100%'
},500);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```